# Canvas game rendering freeze pc

Tags: java

I don't know what is happening but everytime I run this code my computer totally freezes and I can't do anything...it used to work on windows but on linux is freezes? What's wrong with it?

```
package game;

import java.awt.Canvas;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Gaming extends Canvas implements Runnable {


    private Thread thread;

    public Gaming(){
    }

    public void start(){
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame j = new JFrame();
        Gaming g = new Gaming();
        j.add(g);
        j.setVisible(true);
        j.setSize(800,600);
        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        g.start();

    }

    public void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            render();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're going to ask a question that you want us to put effort into solving, put some effort into making that question presentable. That means every sentence starts with a capital letter, everything is spelled out, and the contractions have apostrophes, and most importantly, **all the code is formatted correctly**. I've gone through and fixed it this time, but next time, you need to do that yourself.

Comment: Try adding `Thread.sleep(16)` after `render` and allow the system some time to breath...

Answer (score 0):

1.I see is that you don't use:

```
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        create your jFrame here
    }
});
```

2.I see that this code has no sense at all. What are you trying to achieve?

3.What are you trying to achieve by repainting loop?(your code below)

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        render();
    }
}
```

Comment: Running a black square on canvas, i have done this before and when i run it i see the square but my whole pc start to freeze lol...

Comment: @FabrizioGonzalezCastellanos What do you mean by "running a square"?

Comment: Point 3 is mute the OP is using their own `BufferStrategy`, which circumvents the normal painting process...

Answer (score 0):

- Add a delay of some kind after you call render to allow the system the opportunity to actually push the graphics to hardware and update the screen
- Read through the JavaDocs for [`BufferStrategy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) for an example of how it should be used, you're neglecting the fact that updates can be lost due to other changes in the system and other factors
- Don't forget to clear the `Graphics` context before painting to it...

For example...

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Gaming extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private Thread thread;

    public Gaming() {
    }

    public void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame j = new JFrame();
                Gaming g = new Gaming();
                j.add(g);
                j.setVisible(true);
                j.setSize(800, 600);
                j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                g.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        do {
                 // The following loop ensures that the contents of the drawing buffer
            // are consistent in case the underlying surface was recreated
            do {
                         // Get a new graphics context every time through the loop
                // to make sure the strategy is validated
                Graphics graphics = bs.getDrawGraphics();

                // Render to graphics
                graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                graphics.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
                // Dispose the graphics
                graphics.dispose();

                         // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer contents
                // were restored
            } while (bs.contentsRestored());

            // Display the buffer
            bs.show();

            // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer was lost
        } while (bs.contentsLost());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            render();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(16);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```